# OPEN VPN ERROR windows

Tags: windows, openvpn

I have a problem from many days. I hope that someone can help me. I have Windows 7 and I work with OPENVPN on three environments. On two I work correctly but for one VPN environment I cannot work. When I try to connect to it. I receive this warning:

> WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
>
> Bad encapsulated packet length from peer (15432), which must be > 0 and <= 1627 -- please ensure that --tun-mtu or --link-mtu is equal on both peers -- this condition could also indicate a possible active attack on the TCP link --
> [Attempting restart...]
> Mon Nov 26 18:06:39 2018 Connection reset, restarting [0]

I try to install the most recent version of VPN but nothing.

Comment: Please add your configuration to the question.

Comment: Please include the OpenVPN server and CCD configuration.

Comment: Hi, we are using the last version https://swupdate.openvpn.org/community/releases/openvpn-install-2.4.6-I602.exe.

Comment: How can I recover ccd configuration?